# Generate Code Analysis Report from SonarQube after Integrating with SonarLint Intellij

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

Is it possible to generate code analysis report from SonarQube after integrating with SonarLint intellij. I know we can configure Sonarlint to use same rules defined in SonarQube but could not find anything on Google to generate reports as well from SonarQube after integrating with Sonarlint Intellij but someone from different team told me its possible. Could someone please let me know if its possible or not.

SonarLint shows code issues in Intellij but Can we post same issues list on SonarQube as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the connections to your sonarqube server in sonarlint the last page lets you tick a checkbox to receive remote notifications.

[image: sonarlint/qube notification link]